# PHP Session doesn't exist on index.php

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error while checking for user session on index.php. Once a user has logged on, I want to display a "Log out" button in the menu. This is the code:

session.php

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   session_start();

   $user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];

   $ses_sql = mysqli_query($db,"select username from users where username = '$user_check' ");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($ses_sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   $login_session = $row['username'];

?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
   include('session.php');
?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css" />
<title>LVRP</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top-line"></div>

<div id="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="logo"> </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="/forum" target="_blank">Forums</a></li>
            <li><a class="inactive" href="ucp.php">User Control Panel</a></li>
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){echo('<li><a class="inactive" href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>');} ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="content">

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

It returns **Notice: Undefined index: login_user in /var/www/html/session.php on line 5** on index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"It dies with a blank page."**

Enable errors using

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

At the top of your page, in your PHP tags and post the error.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't know you hade to enable errors.

Displays: **Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/html/config.php on line 7**

Does it mean www-data doesn't have the right permission in linux?

Comment: When you log onto to MySQL what password do you use?
And put that in the password slot.

Comment: It's an alphanumeric password with this format: **Aaaaaaaa1**

Comment: Changed the password in the server and in the PHP-page. Seems to connect now. Don't know what happened but I guess I got the wrong PW somewhere. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Re-reading now you've changed the question; 

The '$_SESSION['login_user'];' variable isn't defined, you can define it by simply just assigning a variable/text to it. e.g $_SESSION['login_user'] = 'Bill';

Either, you've forgot to define it, or you're getting mixed up with the windows authentication 'LOGON_USER', which would be:

'$_SERVER['LOGON_USER'];'

Comment: But what happens if I define every login user to "Bill"? Wouldn't that screw up the user sessions if more people are browsing at the same time?

Comment: Ideally, you'll have a form which validates a user login, in which you take the username from the submitted form, and if the password is correct, then assigns a A session variable to the username;

$_SESSION['User'] = $_POST['Username'];

Or something like that, check [THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) out.

Comment: I've got a login form which defines $_SESSION["login_user"] = $myusername. The problem is that if the player has not logged in, it returns the error. I just want to check if user is logged in on index.php and if he is, display the log out button.

Comment: You need an Isset on your session.php page, that checks if the user has logged on, the include at the moment acts as if every single user will log on, and obviously if they haven't they it'll throw an error. so like:

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
$user_check = $_SESSION['login_user'];
//and the rest of your sql query etc here
}else{
//do nothing, they aren't logged on so we don't need to run the query

}

Answer (score 1):

try the following corrections:

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT ID FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' and password = '$mypassword'";

      $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
      //$active = $row['active'];
      $active = $row['ID'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

      if($count == 1) {
         // This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. (From: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)
         //session_register("myusername");
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;

         header("location: ucp.php");
      }else {
         $error = "Wrong username/password.";
         echo "<pre>";var_dump($error);exit();
      }
   }
?>
```

Comment: This works, however I'm trying to add a link in the menu as soon as the user is logged in. I've pasted the code in the OP.